# How to test a handler function which is wrapped in middy?

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, middy

I want to test my handler which is wrapped in middleware using `middy` like this:

```
const main = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  // .... //
};

export const handle = middy(main)
  .use(httpJsonBodyParser())
  .use(customMiddleWare(ID))
  .use(httpErrorHandler());
```

I want to ignore middy and all middleware and just want to test `main` by passing in mock events and expecting the result but I have no idea how to do it without exporting main.

Answer (score 0):

You can `export const main = ...` or have main in it's own file that's imported into the handler file.